# How add gap after every sentence inside a single element | Different line-height value in one element

Tags: html, css, reactjs, card

I'm building a notes app like google keep with react. My html-css for a single note element is:

```
const NoteList = ({searchTerm}) => {
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchNotes(){
            const response = await fetch("url")
            const notes = await response.json();

            setNotes(notes)
        };
        fetchNotes();
    }, []);

    return (<div className="note-list">
        {notes.map((note) => (
            <div key={note.id}>
                <Note
                    id={note.id}
                    title={note.title}
                    content={note.content}
                />
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>);
};
```

```css
.card{
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: var(--card-bg);
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 var(--card-shadow);
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```

And the data I got from json is something like this:

```js
[{
    "id": 31,
    "title": "Personal Development Goals",
    "content": "1. Read one book per month\n2. Practice mindfulness meditation daily\n3. Take a public speaking course\n4. Learn a new skill or hobby\n5. Volunteer regularly\n6. Start a gratitude journal\n7. Set and track personal fitness goals"
}]
```

The output look like this.

[image]

I want more space after every finished sentence. **NOT SAME HEIGHT** for every line (not line-height). But bigger gaps between sentences.

### This should be the output

[image]

### What I've tried

I've tried bunch of line and letter property.

```
.card{
    line-height: 1.2;
    line-break: loose;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    word-spacing: 1px;
}
```

But it doesn't achieve what I want.

### What I Want

[image]

If you look carefully, you would see that the red `gap` is smaller that `blue` . I've obviously tried `line-height` , `word-wrap`  But I couldn't find any property that can achieve this.

I've seen some online solution but they used multiple `span`  inside a single element. But my data isn't static it retrieves from API in `JSON` format.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am new in react.

Comment: Have you considered splitting the JSON content by new lines, and wrapping each in a paragraph tag?

Something like: ```const contentArray = jsonResult.content.split(/\r?\n/);```

This would give you an array of lines of content, which you could then wrap in paragraph tags.

Comment: This would be an easy fix if the markup was in `<ul>` and `<ol>`—i.e. ordered list (see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol)). Do you have any control over the `JSON` object itself? For instance, the `"content"` can use an array of strings, rather than one big string, then you can easily `map` each item in the array into an `ol` element and style with CSS.

Comment: I am using react. So the content shows with the html. Although react has dangerouslySetInnerHTML attribute. But this can potentially introduce security vulnerabilities. I find a package called html-react-parser. Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each "goal" in a p tag, then apply a css rule for p tag margins. example:

html:

```
<p>goal 1</p> 
<p>goal 2</p>
```

and so on...

Then -

CSS:

```
p {
    margin-top: use px, em, or rem. whichever works best for you and play around with the sizes until you like the look.; }
```

That will apply a margin above each p tag forcing a space between tags and NOT individual lines.

Answer (score 0):

have u try to use multiple p

like  :

```
<div class="card">
  <h5 class="card-title">Personal Development Goals</h5>
  <div class="card-content">
    <p>1. Read one book per month on personal development or self-improvement.</p>
    <p>2. Exercise at least 3 times per week.</p>
    <p>3. Practice mindfulness meditation for at least 15 minutes per day.</p>
    <p>4. Learn a new skill or take a course to improve my career prospects.</p>
    <p>5. Volunteer at least once per month to give back to my community.</p>
    <p>6. Set aside time each week to work on personal projects and hobbies.</p>
    <p>7. Practice gratitude by writing in a journal every day.</p>
    <p>8. Improve my time management skills by setting and sticking to a daily schedule.</p>
    <p>9. Set and work towards specific, measurable, achievable, relevant, and time-bound (SMART) goals.</p>
    <p>10. Seek out opportunities for personal growth and development, such as attending workshops or events.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You will have more control over what you do, you can also use the CSS functionality that allows you to select a child:

```
.card > p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This suggestion isn't helpful as-is. The note card's content returned by the API is in a single property as per the original question. Unless the author does something to convert it to an array, they can't wrap each line with a `p` tag. @Vanita's suggestion (as a direct comment on the question) to split the `content` property using a regex should allow the OP to wrap each entry in a note card with a `p` tag.